# 2010 Mercury Milan Headlight alignment

Tags: headlight, alignment, mercury

Is there any way to adjust the vertical alignment of the headlights on my Milan? The driver's side headlight shines up too high. Also, there is a dark spot in the middle of the beam. Could these two problems be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjustment screws should be located either on the top of the headlamp assembly, behind the headlamp assembly, or near the frame rail by the radiator support.

Once you have adjusted the bulb, see if the dark area goes away. It could be connected with the alignment.

Comment: Horizontal screw should be near the vertical screw.  Make sure to check out proper headlight alignment though.  Don't just aim it where you think you should, do the measurements.